# Add javascript to iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frames

I want to know if it is possible to add a javascript `<script type="text/javascript">blahblah</script>` to an iframe OR frameset that is on the page?

Just a note: the content comes from the same domain `www.domain.com` but the subdomain is different `www.blah.domain.com vs www.blah2.domain.com`, I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: Source of the iframe from the same domain of the parent page?

Comment: Same domain, different sub domain?? Does that matter?

Comment: Can you modify the page being loaded in the `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does matter but luckily there's a fairly simple fix. You just need to set the `document.domain` property on both sides to the same domain (e.g., `document.domain = 'domain.com'`)

`document.domain` can only be set to the same super domain so you couldn't do this with `www.example.com` and `blah.example2.com`.

Once you have the `document.domain` property set you should be able to interface the iframe the same way you would if they were on the same subdomain.

Here's *how* to insert the script tag into the iFrame: [Insert a Script into a iFrame's Header, without clearing out the body of the iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656960/insert-a-script-into-a-iframes-header-without-clearing-out-the-body-of-the-ifr)