# Adding JS to an empty iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to add a JavaScript file to the header of an iframe so that upon loading, the iframe can before a "background task" for me. Currently the iframe is empty, because there is no source I want it to display. Namely, all the iframe will do is perform the script I wish to supply to it.

I have tried suggestions from here:

1. [Can't append <script> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element/3603496#3603496)
2. [Insert a Script into a iFrame's Header, without clearing out the body of the iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656960/insert-a-script-into-a-iframes-header-without-clearing-out-the-body-of-the-ifr)
3. [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)
4. [Calling javascript function in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe)
5. http://www.getallfix.com/2013/08/how-to-include-or-add-external-javascript-file-to-iframe-how-to-add-js-to-iframe/

Yet I cannot get a simple  "write" to the iframe to work.
Here's the code I am working with:

**demo.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="demo.js"></script>  

<script>  
addScript('demo.js');  

function addScript(src){
// Find the iFrame
var iframe = document.getElementById('test');
var val = '<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></scr' + 'ipt>';

var headID = iframe.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         

var newScript = iframe.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'demo.js';
headID.appendChild(newScript);

</script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="output">  
        <iframe id="test"></iframe>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**demo.js**

```
document.write("Hello, I'm a Demo.");
```

Comment: You've to call `addScript` after the `iframe` has been parsed.

Comment: @Teemu Which `iframe`? The actual element or the variable?

Comment: The element must exist before you can get a reference to it with `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add directly the content string

http://jsfiddle.net/0m5axpxx/

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var html = '<body><scr'+ 'ipt>alert(1)</s' + 'cript>Content</body>';
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `iframe.contentWindow.document` instead of just `iframe` for some of your calls. Also, `demo.js` is in the outside page, not inside the iframe, so you either need to give an absolute path (i.e. http://www.example.com/demo.js) or you need to set the contents of the script. This worked for me:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('test');
var headID = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         

var newScript = iframe.contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
newScript.innerHTML = 'document.write("Hello, I\'m a Demo")';
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
headID.appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null"

Comment: Sorry, I only changed the part below so I didn't think to include the declaration of `iframe` above it. I updated the answer